# How can I build a simple calculator with Vue.js, using v-model and maybe v-if?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I need to build a simple component in Vue.Js where there is an input field that is showing number of hours an user would save if they switch to our software.  How can I use the v-if directive:

If they are spending 20 - 30 hours, they would save 10 hours / mo,
30 - 50 hours, they would save 20 hours / mo.
Here is my setup for html:

```
<div id="app">
<label> How Many Hours Do You spent per Month doing Invoicing
<input v-model="{{ hours }}" />
<p v-if="hours <=20 "> You could save {{hours}} hours every month </p>
<p v-else-if="hours > 20 ">You could save {{hours}} hours every month</p>
</div>
new Vue({
    el: '#calc',
         data() {
            return {
               hours:
               save: 
                   }
       },
```

Comment: can you show the code you have tried?

Comment: also, when doing questions on SO ( it's not like a forum ) if your title isn't a question, you are probablly not going to end up with a valid question for SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi anaisUx and welcome to SO.

You need to produce some kind of code example. What have you tried? What doesn't work?

But to answer your question about v-if: v-if isn't gonna help you with your problem. v-if is used in VueJS templates to indicate if the element should be rendered or not.  What you are describing here is some kind of business logic, that you shouldn't put in your templates but inside your compenent and then render the results in your template.

Without beeing too harsh it looks like you are very new to VueJS and programming in general, so I'm gonna guide you in the right direction.

1. Create your VuuJS app: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Getting-Started
2. Create your input (time spent) and bind it to a data-property: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Handling-User-Input
3. Time saved is dependant on time spent, so computed property looks like something that might work: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html
4. Write your business logic with simple if statements.

In other words:

1. Create a data-property named timespent
2. Create a input in your template and bind it to timespent
3. Create a computed property called timesaved that uses timespent to calculate how much time the customer would save.
4. Render timesaved in your template

Expected result: As soon as a customer types something in your input the VueJS app should render timesaved to the template. This should update automatically.

You can practice on codepen, jsfiddle, codesandbox.io/s/vue or any other similar site and post your code here to get some feedback.

Edit: Since you've made an effort and tried a little, here is a working example:

https://codepen.io/bergur/pen/WqPjNo

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {  
    return {
      hours: ''       
    }
  },
  computed: {
    save() {
      if (this.hours > 0 && this.hours < 20) {
        return 1
      }
      if (this.hours >= 20 && this.hours < 30) {
        return 10
      }
      
      if (this.hours >= 30 && this.hours < 50) {
        return 20
      }            
      
      if (this.hours >= 50) {
        return 30
      }            
    }
  }
})
```

Data property hours stores how many hours the customer is spending on invoicing. Like i mentioned above there is no need for multiple v-if, the business logic should stay in the component.

I used a computed property save wjich stores the hours the custumer can save.

Comment: I'd like to add CodeSandbox into the list of practice sites. It's really good at emulating a Vue CLI project with Webpack and single-file components ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/vue

Comment: Added the code, sorry, this is my first time posting in here, hope to get a solution to my problem.

Comment: No problem, we all have to start somewhere. Do you have a link to your example? By the look of your code you're missing the script tag for your vue app.

Comment: It is added, but I didn’t host it anywhere, data binding is working, the calculator snippet it what I need, but cannot find an example anywhere.

Comment: <input v-model="{{ hours }}" /> should be <input v-model="hours" />

Comment: I've updated my answer with a working example, since you have tried to produce some code.

Comment: Wow, that is exactly what I needed, thanks a lot for your time, you saved me!

Comment: No problem. I would appreciate if you could mark the answer as the corrected one if you are satisfied with it.